# iOS Notification Content Extension - How to pass data to app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wrote a custom `Notification Content Extension` for my `Push Notifications` like this:

[image]

The thing is, whenever the user is on a certain item in the carousel, I want the `GO TO APP` button to send a `String` to the app when it's opening, and from there, handle that string to move the user to the correct `ViewController`.

I already have the handling part inside the app, I just need to know how to pass that String from the `Notification Content Extension` to the container app.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable app groups in capabilities and use suite userDefaults to write the key and read it in the app

```
    NSUserDefaults*defaults= [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.company.appName"];

 // Write in extension
   [defaults setObject:@"anyThing" forKey:@"sharedContent"];

 // Read in app
  [defaults objectForKey:@"sharedContent"];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I couldn't figure it out because no one said I need to activate the App Groups on the Extension target also (why does every tutorial forgets to mention that?). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your app is configured for Universal Links or you have defined a Custom URL Scheme for your app, you can also open your app's URL (e.g. with data in query parameters) by calling

```
extensionContext?.open(url)
```

in your `NotificationViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13, Swift 5.

Based on the answer by [Sh_Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5820010/sh-khan), here is some Swift Syntax. Obviously I have added App Group as a capability to the target of the main app + the target of the extension, naming the group as "group.ch.Blah" for this example.

Setting your app group, saving a string in our case, needed to set the type as Any cause strings not a type that is available in groups.

```
let localK = getPrivateKey64() as Any
let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.ch.Blah")
defaults?.set(localK, forKey: "privateK")
```

Setting your app group, and reading the string back, needed to recast it back to string.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.ch.Blah")
let localK = defaults?.object(forKey: "privateK") as? String
```

Worked perfectly with a notification service extension.